# How to store an image to riak and get it from riak?

Tags: riak

In my project now, I need to store some images to Riak, then get them from Riak and display them in HTML page.

Here is an API I encapsulated:

```
//inputstream is a stream of an image
byte[] imageContent = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
String descriptiveId = null;
String storedImageId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
BlobContent blobContent = new BlobContent(imageContent,descriptiveId);
riakBlobDAO.create(storedImageId,blobContent);
```

.....

```
//get the byte[] from riak by the uuid
   BlobContent returnedBlobContent  = riakBlobDAO.get(storedImageId);
   byte[] returnedImageContent = returnedBlobContent.getData();
```

if i invoke this method,it will return sth,but for this `<img src="xxxx">`,i can't 
get the src from the returned sth, so any other solutions?

I know the image stored in riak is binary bytes, but I am confused that how can I get it from riak and display it in HTML page.

I know that  `<img src="xxxx" />`,but if an image stored in Riak,can i generate the image url ?

Comment: when you try `<img src="xxxx">`, what do you get?  If you try that URL with `curl -v` does the content-type header have the correct value?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are storing image's data as a BLOB in Riak and retrieving the same. With this stored BLOB, if you try retrieving it and do something like this in your HTML:

```
<img src="*<...retrieved BLOB data...>*" /img>
```

then it's not bound to work. The ideal way is to save this BLOB as a file (maybe a temporary file in /tmp) with proper extension and then use the same path into your HTML.

As an additional point, if your image's BLOB is in a format which is supported by newer browsers under HTML5, then you could also pass the data directly using following format:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, ....." />
```

More info on it here: [Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

Although, beware that the above way is subject to varying behaviors on different browsers.